# Can't seem to write a generic read & write

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I need to write & read to binary streams. It would seem like `BinaryWriter` & `BinaryReader` would fit nicely, but `BinaryReader` is not generic in any sense of the word, and AFAIK `BinaryWriter` doesn't seem to be extendable to anything beyond primitives. Coming from C++ & knowing that C# also have generic programming techniques I thought this would be an easy problem to fix.

In C++ I'd write something along the lines of:

```
// Default works for primitives since BinaryWriter::Write has overloads
template< typename SinkT, typename SourceT >
static void Save( SinkT& a_Sink, const SourceT& a_Source )
{
    a_Sink.Write( a_Source );
}

// Lets create a better match for some 3rd party vector3 type
template< typename SinkT >
static void Save( SinkT& a_Sink, const SomeVendor::Vector3& a_Source )
{
    Save( a_Sink, a_Source[0] );
    Save( a_Sink, a_Source[1] );
    Save( a_Sink, a_Source[2] );
}
```

By providing a better match I can easily support serialization for both my own types and 3rd party types. Is there a way to do a similar solution i C#? I've tried with both generic helper classes & static function but can't quite seem to get it to mesh.

Comment: I sympathise, I could be wrong, but it seems like a lot of the C# IO operations were written before generics so don't use them, which is a little disappointing. 
However, to do the first method, that can be done using generics with constraints if that is what you are trying to do?
Update: Thinking about it, you can just overload the method to do specialisation

Comment: Awesome, I guess I'll need to take a look at constraints and how they work, I'm guessing it's a bit like concepts in C++?

Comment: Can you add your attempts at a generic helper class and a static function?

Comment: @Ylisar I don't know much about concepts, but I believe they are a similar principle. Basically they allow you to specify what the class must inherit from (either interface or class) and a couple of other things (like be a value type or ref type)

Comment: @T.Kiley Ah, in C++ there's no limitations on inheritance, only that the type fulfills specific requirements often restricted to its interface and the implications of that interface. The problem is that I need to serialize types whose interface I can't change, but perhaps a helper class could provide the indirection needed.

Comment: It's worth noting if you are using latest .net you can use the `dynamic` keyword which allows you to call any method and assume it exists

Comment: C# does have generics -- of a sort -- but what you're looking for is called partial specialization IIRC.  That's one of the things I *really*, *really* miss from C++.  As @T. Kiley points out you can achieve some of this with constraints, but it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as we discussed in the comments there are 2 solutions:

**Generics with constraints**

```
static void Save<T, U>(T sink, U source) where T : IWriter,
                                               U : ISerializable
{
       // do stuff using that fact that U is serialisable and T implements IWriter
}
```

where IWriter would be:

```
interface IWriter
{
     void Save<U>(U itemToSave) where U : ISerializable;
}
```

To do the specialisation, you would just overload the method. See [this example](http://ideone.com/jjryQR) for how that would work.

**`dyanamic` type**

You can use the `dynamic` type to allow you to call arbitary methods, but you loose compile time type checking.

```
static void Save(dynamic a, dynamic b)
{
      a.Save(b);
}
```

I'm not sure how that would work with overloading to provide the specialisation you require.

Answer (score 1):

What you want (templates) simply do not exist in C#. You can do something hacky and use `dynamic` (to duck-type your way around it), but I really don't recommend it. You may need to simply find a different approach.

Comment: Might just go dirty on it and brute force hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use BinaryFormatter to serialize/deserialize objects to and from a binary stream, if that's what you need.

[BinaryFormatter documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Might be what I'm looking for, taking a look!